# Is eth-proxy still a thing in 2021?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, ethminer

I've been mining with my several GPUs on https://ethermine.org and while doing a research on how to increase mining efficiency, I've found ethproxy project on GitHub (https://github.com/Atrides/eth-proxy) which boast an increase of 20% of hashrate. Could someone please explain what ethproxy is/does and if it is still a thing because project is abandoned since 2016. Was its functionality replaced by Stratum V2? As I understand, while mining in a pool, my GPUs mine independent of each other, while proxy allows them to work in tandem on a chunk of calculations? Sorry, still learning the ropes and obviously have a basic understanding about mining.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly eth-proxy was created, because back then the mining software (e.g ethminer) did not support the stratum protocol directly.

The mining software would poll the pool for a new job every 200ms or so (depending on the  configuration) AKA "getwork method".

With increasing numbers of miners connecting to a pool, this significantly increased to pool network utilization - so pools were eager to implement the stratum protocol to more efficiently push new work to miners.

eth-proxy is a bridge between a stratum-pool and a non-stratum-miner (i.e using the polling getWork method).

Today all popular mining softwares directly support the stratum protocol (or even more than one stratum-protocol variation) and thus eliminate the need for eth-proxy.

Using eth-proxy today would just add a delay and make mining less efficient.

Also, eth-proxy does not manage multiple GPUs, it manages one or multiple mining rigs. So you would use it to connect with multiple PCs (with any amount of GPUs).

If you have multiple GPUs in your rig and you run a single instance of a mining software, your GPUs will NOT mine independently on the pool. The mining software will take care of allocating the work to the GPUs.